Vote to close when you see bad or off topic questions
I have recently closed some questions. The common thing was that I was the only one doing that.
Many users have the privilege, they can vote to close... yet no-one does. So my message is: If you see a bad question, you should vote to close.
When you see a good post, you vote up, when it's wrong or not useful or not clear, you vote down. When something just doesn't belong, then vote to close. That's what we are supposed to do as a community. Mods are an extra help, they are not supposed to be the only ones who take the decisions. Now the community is small, but then it'll grow and it will be impossible for just some mods to handle everything.
This is why high-rep users have such privileges, so they can help. You are almost-mods, so prove that high reputation by actively participating.

Some feedback would be accepted. Remember that this is a community-based site. If the community doesn't do what it's supposed to do, the site will lose activity and might be closed because of it.

Vote to close awful questions... Edit those that can be saved.

It takes 500 reputation to vote to close. There are barely 20 members on the site that have that reputation (or higher). Some them barely so, meaning that they got this right only recently.
It takes 5 votes to close (other than mods). Getting five out of 20, or one fourth, of the eligibles to close any one question can be difficult. And that's one fourth of TODAY's eligibles, not, say, last week's.
I see "bad" questions, but don't have enough reputation on this site. I have high reputation on other sites, which is why I can see bad questions. Maybe there should be a rule that someone should be able to vote to close after receiving 500 reputation on ANY SE site.

First of all, thanks for posting. :) Second... The point is that no-one ever voted, as far as I can remember/tell. Few votes? Ok, but the problem is that no-one ever closes, and the majority of those users have been "high-rep" for a while, it's not a matter of "yesterday". Probably, it's just that the site is still growing, some don't know, etc., so I'll wait, but I wanted to raise the problem so people would pay more attention. If you can't vote yet, you can flag. Correct flagging would increase your flag count. :)

Welcome to Chinese.SE, Tom. I think I've run into you on the board games site. Even if we never get five votes to close bad questions, those votes are still useful feedback to the moderators. I'll be more likely to close a question if I see it already has two close votes.

@DonKirkby Agreed! We'll get the 5 votes when the site starts to grow, for now, some feedback is fine! :)

I may be the one that doesn't like to vote to close. Hmm, actually, I have done such votes for very few times if I remember.
I have a doubt, now that I have a high reputation, will a post be closed right after I click vote-to-close?Actually, I don't want to see this(when my reputation wasn't so high, I found a post would be closed with 5 votes to close). I think this forum is mainly for foreigners to learn Chinese, and perhaps my perspective is too different from the foreigners. For some a question, I would think it's not useful while other memebers don't agree. This is what I am concerning.
Perhaps I am too careful...

Only mods votes are binding. Any other user can't vote to close instantly. If you think the question deserves to be closed for a certain reason, then vote! It's useful that the first person posts a comment so other users can see if the reason was good or not. If it's good others will follow your example. If not the question will stay open and nothing will happen! :)
